# How to redirect from /pages to layouts/error.vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a error.vue file within the layouts folder which should show the UI for a 400, 404, 410 and 500 error. But, it is not showing the ones I created, it is still showing the default NuxtServerError page.

So, my question is how can I show my created UI within a page.

Below is the code that I am using within the layouts/error.vue

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="error-container">
    <div class="error-content" v-if="error.statusCode === 404">
      <div>
        <h1>Sorry, the page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
        <p>You can return to our <nuxt-link to="/">home page</nuxt-link> or <a href="mailto:contact@web.co">contact</a> us if you can't find what you are looking for.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="~/assets/Images/404.png">
    </div>

    <div class="error-content" v-if="error.statusCode === 400">
      <div>
        <h1>Sorry, the page you are looking for doesn't exist anymore.</h1>
        <p>You can return to our <nuxt-link to="/">home page</nuxt-link> or <a href="mailto:contact@web.co">contact</a> us if you can't find what you are looking for.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="~/assets/Images/404.png">
    </div>

    <div class="error-content" v-if="error.statusCode === 410">
      <div>
        <h1>Sorry, the page you are looking for has been deleted.</h1>
        <p>You can return to our <nuxt-link to="/">home page</nuxt-link> or <a href="mailto:contact@web.co">contact</a> us if you can't find what you are looking for.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="~/assets/Images/404.png">
    </div>

    <div class="error-content" v-if="error.statusCode === 500">
      <div>
        <h1>Sorry, the page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
        <p>You can return to our <nuxt-link to="/">home page</nuxt-link> or <a href="mailto:contact@web.co">contact</a> us if you can't find what you are looking for.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="~/assets/Images/404.png">
    </div>
  </div>  
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Lost?'
    }
  },
  props: ['error'],
  layout: 'error'
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style scoped>
.error-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.error-content {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto 200px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.error-content > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.error-content > div > h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.error-content > img {
  width: 200px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: unset;
  color: var(--color-tpBlue);
}
</style>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redirect to `error` layout does not happen automatically. Instead, redirect should be done in relevant hooks or methods of your application. It is done by calling `error` method available in Nuxt [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#context) with `statusCode` and `message` props passed, which will replace page with with content of `layout/error.vue` and will respond with HTTP status provided as a `statusCode` prop.

Here is an example of handling errors inside [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#handling-errors):

```
export default {
  async asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
      return { title: data.title }
    } catch (e) {
       error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it has helped. But, I have another question, how can I place more than one error message statusCode within the catch? Many thanks!

Comment: One option is to check status code of error response from axios and call `error` method with appropriate props. Another is to create a helper function that will return valid props depending on error response (for example, with `switch` statement check).

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @aBiscuit answer:

For the ones who want to redirect to the error page in another context than `asyncData` in your component, you can access the `error` function in `this.$nuxt.error`.